# Upgrading flutter broke dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, firebase-authentication

I just upgraded Flutter to 1.5, Android Studio to 3.4 and my dependencies (mentionable Firebase) and my app does no longer run on my device. It is being installed and directly crashes with following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;

Downgrading flutter to an older version and downgrading Android Studio did both not work. My personal assumption is, that it has something to do with the change from ProGuard to R8.

This is how my current ***proguard-rules.pro*** file looks like:

```
 #Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

***app/build.gradle:***

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
...    
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

***flutter doctor:***

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.475], locale de-AT)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.33.1)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

***pubspec.yaml***

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker:
  path_provider:
  google_maps_flutter:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:
  image_cropper:
  firebase_storage:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  google_sign_in:
  flutter_facebook_login:
  http:
  location:
  geoflutterfire:
  firebase_messaging:
  cached_network_image:
  share:
  camera:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view:
```

Comment: tried with the flutter clean command?

Comment: Yes, several times. I even cloned the entire project on my laptop and got the same issue.

Comment: post your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: // Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Did you follow the doc? https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: I do have the line in my file.
Yes, I followed the docs. The app used to work before I did the update of the dependencies/android studio/flutter. Actually the update changed the google-services version to 4.2.0. Changing it back to 3.2.1, cleaning the project and running did also not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dependencies to this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
}
```

Also take care about this, if u are using some other plugins like firebase messaging you need to add it also.

Here a list with the new releases

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

One more thing about this changes, you need to update your flutter firebase plugins to the latest version or you're going to have stability problems and unexpected crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, for me problem was due to minification,
try setting

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Do a flutter clean
Then build your project

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me. I also tried to set `useProguard false` in the debug part of the buildTypes, but still the same problem. Is there maybe more I need to do than cleaning if I change something in the `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

changed latest firebase-messaging google dependencies and modified other dependencies also in a same version in app gradle file. working fine now

[dependencies version detail you can refer here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
}
```